# Display the version name in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am planning to display the version code on my xml files but I am have an error to display the text.

My Activity Code

```
    val displayVersion = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.app_version)
    val appVersion = getString(R.string.app_version)
    val versionName: String = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
    displayVersion.text = "$appVersion $versionName"
```

My XML Code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_version"
    android:layout_below="@+id/splash_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="TextView"/>
```

Error Code

```
displayVersion.text = "$appVersion $versionName"
```

Maybe this error code are incorrect, because every-time I that code the app will works if the code exist the app will lunch but eventually it will automatically crash.

Comment: try displayVersion.text = "{$appVersion $versionName}" to see if it works.

Comment: @DinoTw I think the problem is with displayVersion.text the app will crash. Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: You might need to add a stack trace log when your app got crashed.

Comment: @Pemassi this was the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you bind layout before get `app_version` control? For example, `setContentView(R.layout.layout_one);` The error message said, cannot get the control.

Comment: @Pemassi it was fixed already hahahaha I put the setContentView below the codes I provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error because I put the layout below to the code I provided above

I just put this code above **setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)**

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_name) <-- This is the root cause of my concern
val displayVersion = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.app_version)
val appVersion = getString(R.string.app_version)
val versionName: String = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
displayVersion.text = "$appVersion $versionName"
```

My Error Code

```
val displayVersion = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.app_version)
val appVersion = getString(R.string.app_version)
val versionName: String = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
displayVersion.text = "$appVersion $versionName"
setContentView(R.layout.layout_name) <--This should be put above
```